# By using Wordpress Elementor plugin, I cannot create any blank landing page template : why?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've got a blog and I use *Wordpress 5.2.3* as well as the free theme *Stargazer* that I love. I'd like to use *Elementor* plugin (free version) in order to create landing pages.

First I had to download another plugin (*Blank Slate*) to generate blank pages because **there wasn't that option in the basic model page attributes**.

Then the problem's that even with this plugin **there is still a brown background relict from my main theme**. I wish I had a perfect blank page, do you see ?  :)

Do you think you could help me ?

I searched for solutions but I only found people who look for the contrary of  what I ask for, that's to say they try to avoid blank pages...

I wish I could give you some screenshots but I've to get 10 reputation to do it...

Friendly.

Comment: Why do you want completely blank page?

Comment: I want a blank page to train myself by making landing pages. Moreover the more a landing page is neutral the more you can make people focuse on CTAs.